# Can you run excel macros through Node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, vba

I am wondering, if Node.js can open an xlsx (xlsm) file and run an Excel macro.

I know the "xlsx npm" can open up, create and move xlsx files, but I haven't been able to find an answer to whether or not it can run Excel macros.

Comment: Does your server have Excel installed?

Comment: Take a look at Excel JS API ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel?view=office-js ). It might be helpful.

Comment: did you got a solution for this ?